# Half way through running the program stops?

Tags: c++

I've wrote this program and i can't seem to figure out why it will compile, but when it runs it stops mid way? I've removed the reverse_stack and tried without it. Still having the same problem? Does anyone know why this is the case?

Sample Code::

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

void reverse_stack(stack<int>&S, stack<int>& S1, stack<int>& S2){

    while(!S.empty()){
          S1.push(S.top());
          S.pop();
    }

    while(!S1.empty()){
          S2.push(S1.top());
          S1.pop();
    }

    while(!S2.empty()){
        S.push(S2.top());
        S.pop();
    }
}

int main()
{
    stack<int> S, S1, S2;
    S.push(1), S.push(2), S.push(3);

    cout<< "The top element of S is: " <<S.top() << endl;
    reverse_stack(S,S1,S2);

    cout<< "The top element of S is now: " << S.top() << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

OutPut::

```
The Top element of S is: 3
```

Doesn't get past this point here.

Expected OutPut::

```
The Top element of S is: 3
The Top element of S is: 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Your last while loop

```
while(!S2.empty()){
    S.push(S2.top());
    S.pop();
}
```

pops from `S` when it should pop from `S2`.

Comment: Wow thankyou. Tunnel Visioned way to hard on that one :(

Comment: It's okay, buddy. It happens to the best of us. The more you trip over on small problems like this one, the better off you'll be; you'll basically be tech Ghandi! :D -edit (sounds like i'm claiming i fixed this; clarifying i'm not, just being wholesome)